# Laravel 8 - count row from database

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to count column from database but when I get data from database with controller, count is returning just 0. It should be more than. I don't know where is the problem. I'm beginner Laravel by the way. So, how can I count data from database?

**My controller:**

```
public function getProfile($username){
    $follow = Follow::all();
    $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
    if(isset($user)) {
        return view('design2.profile', ['user'=>$user,'follow'=>$follow]);        
    } else {
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
}
```

**My blade is:**

```
@foreach($user->follows as $followr)  
    <h6 >
        <strong>
            {{ count((array)$followr->following_id) }}
        </strong>
    </h6>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Where in the code are you trying to count?

Comment: i updated. sorry

Comment: ....this looks the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66975805/laravel-8-cant-get-data-from-database

Answer (score 1):

Since you are iterating a collection in the `foreach` of blade, you can call the `count()` method of the collections.

The count method returns the total number of items in the collection:

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4]);

$collection->count();

// 4
```

So in your code it would only be.

```
$user->follows->count()
```

Comment: thank you. I have two column in database that one of the name is follower_id and I can count the other column with this your code. so how can I count this follower_id? it's gonna be $user->follows->follower_id->count like this? or something. can you help me again for this?

Comment: `follower_id` is a number, you can't count a number.

Comment: so what can I do in this situation? and I can count number with your code. the other column is number too.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to achieve in the second problem, but you should create another question for the other problem you have. This problem has already been solved.