# Laravel 8 - can't get data from database

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get data from database that name is follower_id but when I try to get data I get error. And when I try with foreach I'm returning null I'm using database with relationships and I can get data if I type `{{$follows}}` . On the other hand, if I type  `{{$follows->follower_id}}` I get this error:

> Property [follower_id] does not exist on this collection instance.

So how can I solve this problem? I'm beginner in Laravel and database relationships by the way.

**My controller is:**

```
public function getProfile($username){

        $follow = Follow::all();
        $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
        if(isset($user)){
        return view('design2.profile', ['user'=>$user,'follow'=>$follow]);        
        }else{
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }
    }
```

**My blade is:**

```
<h6><span class="text-secondary"><strong>{{$follow->follower_id}} follower</strong></span></h6>
```

**My follow model:**

```
public $table = "follow";

protected $fillable = [
    'follower_id',
    'user_id',
];


public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}
```

**My user model:**

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'username',
        'password',
        'info',
        'twitter_name',
        'instagram_name',
        'photo'
    ];

   public function follows(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Follow');
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? It looks like ` $follow`  is a collection of entities

Comment: Show us your models' relations please.

Comment: We don't know anything about your database structure, might want to [edit] your question and maybe paste your migration or model relations. Btw, `$follows` is not set, it's `$follow`

Comment: `Follow::all()` will give you a _collection_ which is like an array. You need to loop over that in your view and get the _follow_id_ from each model.

Comment: sorry guys. i updated

Comment: @reedus6749 I see you created another account just to ask this question? Why?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66975168/laravel-8-count-row-from-database/66975274?noredirect=1#comment118388047_66975274

Comment: @reedus6749 I was looking for that, thank you !

Comment: There are literally thousands of results on Stackoverflow if you search for "Property does not exist on this collection instance". Try to debug your issue before you post yet another duplicate question. They might not all be your specific case, but one of them is surely similar enough to help you, or read the comments on this post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 8 - count row from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66975168/laravel-8-count-row-from-database)

Comment: @MrEduar because this is different question?

Comment: But it was not necessary to create another account. Just another question :D

Comment: @MrEduar you know you can ask a question every 90 minutes

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Sorry, I've never asked two questions so often.

Comment: @TimLewis yes I tried the other solution but I couldn't solve. so that's why I'm asking

Comment: @waterloomatt i tried too with foreach but i can't get any result. it is returning null

Comment: If you tried it, then show what you tried and why it didn't work. "It didn't work" is not descriptive enough.

Comment: okay sorry. i tried @foreach($follow as $followr) and when I type this {{$followr->user->follower_id}}, returning null

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to get all the followers of a user.
Let me do the coding for you so that you have a somewhat more standard code than you have now.

In you User Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The followers that belong to the User
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function followers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'follow', 'user_id', 'follower_id');
    }
}
```

In your controller.

```
/**
 * Gets the user with all his followers.
 *
 * @param string $username
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function getProfile($username){

    $user = User::with('followers')->where('username', $username)->firstOrFail();
    
    return view('design2.profile', [
        'user' => $user,
    ]);
}
```

In your blade.

```
@foreach($user->followers as $follower)
    <h6>
        <span class="text-secondary">
            <strong>{{$follower->name}}</strong>
        </span>
    </h6>
@foreach
```

And that is all.

Comment: thank you but as you know from the previous question I want to count this. I tried {{$follower->name->count()}} but i got error. How can I count that

Comment: I really know what I want. just a count data. i didn't ask how can I get name from database . so my question is how can I count

Comment: Count what? In your question you have only placed that {{$follows->follower_id}} gives you an error, and that's all we have to guess what you want.

Comment: follower_id It is a number. You can't count a number. It's like counting 10. 10 is 10 and that's it.

Comment: okay. so I want to be able to count how many 10 there are.

Comment: You will get only 1. Since `$user->follower_id` will only get a 10. If you want to count how many followers a user has then you should use `$user->followers->count()` as I answered in your last question, I thought that was already clear.

Comment: your answer is counting just a first column(user_id) but i want to count second column(follower_id)